# Online tool to get EVM code of address

Tags: evm

Using the console of an Ethereum client, you can get the binary code of a contract placed on the blockchain. Does an online tool to get this binary code exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your question properly, you would be able to do such things using [Etherscan](https://etherscan.io). Just use the search box to look up for the specific contract (account) address. Then you will be able to check the contract bytecode (or opcodes) and other related information.

Comment: But doesn't Etherscan only show the code if someone has uploaded the source code? I don't care about the source code, I am interested in the EVM code.

Comment: You are right. It does show the binary code even though the source code for the contract has not been submitted:
https://etherscan.io/address/0x442bc47357919446eabc18c7211e57a13d983469#code